# Lasso Generalized linear model in Python

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn, statsmodels, cvxopt

I would like to fit a generalized linear model with negative binomial link function and L1 regularization (lasso) in python.
Matlab provides the nice function :

```
lassoglm(X,y, distr)
```

where distr can be poisson, binomial etc.

I had a look at both statmodels and scikit-learn but I did not find any ready to use function or example that could direct me towards a solution.
In matlab it seems they minimize this:

```
min (1/N * Deviance(β0,β) + λ * sum(abs(β)) )
```

where deviance depends on the link function.

Is there a way to implement this easily with scikit or statsmodels or I should go for cvxopt?

Comment: Just FYI, it is called scikit-learn, not scikit. Scikit-learn has a lasso model with squared loss (e.g. gaussian noise assumption) and l1-regularization. There is also logistic regression with l1-regularization, where the logloss is optimized.

Comment: Thanks I am aware of it but in my question the negative binomial part is essential

Comment: Scikit-learn does not provide this type of model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

statsmodels has had for some time a `fit_regularized` for the discrete models including NegativeBinomial.

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.NegativeBinomial.fit_regularized.html

which doesn't have the docstring (I just saw). The docstring for Poisson has the same information http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.Poisson.fit_regularized.html
and there should be some examples available in the documentation or unit tests.

It uses an interior algorithm with either scipy slsqp or optionally, if installed, cvxopt. Compared to steepest descend or coordinate descend methods, this is only appropriate for cases where the number of features/explanatory variables is not too large.

Coordinate descend with elastic net for GLM is in a work in progress pull request and will most likely be available in statsmodels 0.8.

Comment: Ok but I don't quite get how to retrieve the parameters after I do: 

`nb = NBmodel(mesurements, classes, loglike_method='nb2'); 
nb.fit()`

Comment: you need to look at some examples in the documentation to see how statsmodels works. specifically `fit` returns a results instance, i.e. `results = nb.fit()` `print(results.params)` `print(results.summary()` and `dir(results)`

Comment: Thanks. I was uncorrectly trying to call nb.params. Anyway the implementation does not converge even in trivial cases with regularization and the fit gives negative parameters and this is also happening for poisson ... very strange

Comment: You could try standardizing/z-scoring your variables, and provide an example in the statsmodels github issues. The `exp` function for the mean easily runs into overflow problems if there are explanatory variables with large values. I tried to make the optimization more robust, but there are still often convergence problems with NegativeBinomial and Poisson. to clarify: the L1 regularized method is `fit_regularized`, `fit` is the unpenalized version.